# Fixed the position for popover content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a button and popover content. What I want to do is to keep the button fixed but at the same time keeping the popover content position fixed as well, but am not sure how to do it.

Here is the example I made in fiddle.

```
$("#chatbtn").show().popover({ content: response.text, html: true, placement: 'top' });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8su2/530/

I am not sure how to do add the position fixed property to the content (contents are dynamically generated), such that when the page is scroll up or down it still stays attached to the button.

Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this css

```
.popover{position:fixed;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8su2/534/

Comment: No problem, just be careful if you use the popover in other places. Then it will define position: fixed; for them as well.